# Zip Sub-Assemblies Using maven-assembly-plugin In Multi-Module Maven Build

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multi-module maven build for an enterprise project structured like this:

```
-- Parent
  -- Documentation
  -- Child1
    -- src/main/java
    -- src/main/assembly/assembly.xml
    -- pom.xml
  -- Child2 
    -- src/main/java
    -- src/main/assembly/assembly.xml
    -- pom.xml
-- pom.xml (parent project)
```

Child1 creates a war then the assembly downloads jetty and adds the 2 together in a zip.

Child 2 creates a jar and Tanuki service scripts then the assembly zips them all up.

I want to add these 2 zips and the contents of the Documentation folder to a single zip to give to my clients.

To that end I have added a third module to do the assembly of assemblies.

The assembly.xml looks like this:

```
    <assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
      <id>bin</id>
      <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
      </formats>
      <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

      <moduleSets>
        <moduleSet>
          <includeSubModules>false</includeSubModules>
          <!-- Enable access to all projects in the current multi-module build! -->
          <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>

          <!-- Now, select which projects to include in this module-set. -->
          <includes>
            <include>org.test:Parent</include>
          </includes>
          <sources>
            <outputDirectoryMapping>.</outputDirectoryMapping>
            <fileSets>
              <fileSet>
                <directory>Documentation</directory>
                <includes>
                  <include>README*</include>
                </includes>
              </fileSet>
            </fileSets>
          </sources>
        </moduleSet>
        <moduleSet>
          <includeSubModules>false</includeSubModules>
          <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
          <includes>
            <include>org.test:child1</include>
          </includes>
          <binaries>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <includes>
              <include>*.zip</include>
            </includes>
          </binaries>
        </moduleSet>
      </moduleSets>
    </assembly>
```

The first part gets the Documentation into the zip OK but the binaries section doesn't work.
If I don't specify the includes in the binaries section I end up with the jar and the war in my final zip. I don't want these in my final zip as they are in the child zips.

How can I get the child zips into the final zip?